# ESLint - alias setup

Tags: javascript, eslint

So I am using aliases in my webpack configuration and I have those `eslint` warnings about `no-extraneous-dependencies` etc.

So I installed `eslint-plugin-import` along with `eslint-import-resolver-alias` and configured my `.eslintrc` files like this:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "defaultParams": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/sort-comp": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "prefer-arrow-callback": 0,
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "func-names": 0,
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": [
        // I have my actions folder in ./shared/actions
        ["Actions", "./shared/actions"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My linter is not working with this `settings` options. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to be with your relative path

```
"./shared/actions"
```

Try changing it to

```
"../shared/actions"
```

If that does not work, try an absolute path and take it from there.

Basically, the root directory / current working directory, is not the one you think it is...